# How to fix firebase database ui list adapter

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I think i have written it correctly and i don't know why it is not working, please help here,

[image]

And grade file is as follows

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:17.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.2'

implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.2.0'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using a new version of FirebaseUI, then you need to change the code to the following:

```
FirebaseListOptions<DataClass> options = new FirebaseListOptions.Builder<DataClass>()
    .setQuery(databaseReference, DataClass.class)
    .setLayout(R.layout.List_category_Layout)
    .build();

FirebaseListAdapter<DataClass> adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<DataClass>(options) {
  @Override
 protected void populateView(View v, DataClass model, int position) {
    }
 };
```

First, configure the adapter by building `FirebaseListOptions`, in your case `DataClass` is your model class. `setQuery` will contain the query that you made and the model class.

Next create the FirebaseListAdapter object, that will contain the `populatView` method to bind the data to the view.

Check here for more information:

https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/database#using-firebaseui-to-populate-a-listview

Comment: I am sorry but that did not work as it did not display anything

Comment: you need to also add `startListening()` and `stopListening()`

Comment: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/database#startstop-listening

Comment: THANKS VERY MUCH, IT WORKED

Answer (score 0):

Just use this it will definitely work implementation `'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:2.0.0'`